# Problems with WINE on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wine

I'm running Linux Mint Tricia and I'm having trouble with WINE. I want to run Ren'py because I want to get back to making VN's, but the application (uncompressed) is an executable. So when I run the exe file with wine, nothing happens. It says it's opening renpy.exe but nothing show up, no error message, no Ren'py loading screen, nothing.

I'm not sure what's happening and I want to get back to making VN when I was on Windows. Is it a problem with what I'm doing, mabye WINE is bugged?

Comment: Isn't Ren'py available for Linux Mint as well? As far as I can see it uses python which runs natively and doesn't need Wine. It's also important to note that Wine can't run everything, a good amount of applications don't work with it.

Comment: on the Ren'py website there's a downloadable tar.bz2 file but there's an executable in the file. I can uncompress it into a normal file but the .exe is still there. The website also says it's runs on Linux. Do you know if there is any other way of running Ren'py on Linux?

Comment: The downloads section says it's an SDK. I'm going to try the .exe SDK download, see if anything happens.          Edit: 7-zip pops up to decompress it (or something) but it just leaves the same file with the .exe

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You don't need to go to the website, you can enter the following code into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install renpy
```

To start Ren'py, simply type and execute

```
renpy
```

You also need to download the python-tk package

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Then choose your project directory and text editor and you're set.
It's important to mention that you should not close the terminal whilst Ren'py is in use.